# jquery - set a variable equal to the nearest checkbox object with specified name

Tags: jquery, object

I have a table with multiple rows. each row has the same inputs names with an incremental number attached to it.

```
<table class="table.authors-list">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="first_name_1" id="first_name_1">
            <input type="text" name="last_name_1" id="first_name_1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="treated_1" id="treated_1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="first_name_2" id="first_name_2">
            <input type="text" name="last_name_2" id="first_name_2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="treated_2" id="treated_2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="first_name_3" id="first_name_3">
            <input type="text" name="last_name_3" id="first_name_3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="treated_3" id="treated_3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

on entering information into `first_name_2`, I want to

my jquery function is:

```
function calculateRow(row, cb) {
    if ($(cb).is(':checked')) {
        alert(1);
    } else {
        alert(2);
    }
}
```

I want to call function `calculateRow()` with the below syntax

```
$("table.authors-list").on("change", 'input[name^="discount"]', function (event) {
    var cb = $(this).closest(input[name ^= "treated"]);
    calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"), cb);

});
```

I want to pass two parameters to `calculateRow()` 
`row` is `$(this).closest("tr")`

for `cb` I want it to be the checkbox field.
`var cb = $(this).closest(input[name^="treated"]);`

so when `calculateRow()` executes, the code will check the value of the checkbox named `treatedX` where X is the number of that row.

I have tried to create a fiddle, but it is not working obviously.
http://jsfiddle.net/cmJu6/

so basically, on entering something into the first_name input, the alert must fire depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.siblings` instead of `closest` to get the sibling input-

```
$(this).siblings('input[name^="treated_"]');
```

Also, your selector is wrong `-->` `$("table.authors-list")`

it should be like `$(".table\\.authors-list")`

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/cmJu6/2/

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect. Can you explain `(".table\\.` some more? Thanks pXL.

Comment: @Smudger you are using `.` in class name , as `.` being a class specifier, you need to escape that with \\ .. more info `--->` http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks a million. appreciated.

Comment: Hi pXL, I cant get this working on my real example. I have created a new fiddle with the actual markup generated by php.  please can you see if you can help. Thanks a million. http://jsfiddle.net/c2dp9/1/